# How to connect Android to MySQL online?

Tags: android, mysql

There are a lot tutorials that explain how to connect Android with MySQL but on localhost, But i want to know how to use Android with online database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some cPanel hosting to have the sql database installed on your online storage and have phpmyadmin functions.
Further you can have multiple backend scripts on your server to direct the flow of data. (Uses a url provided by the hosting provider).

If that answers your question!